# Replace string for numeric labels for classification

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, integer

For a classification problem I want to replace different country codes by numbers representing the class. The column below is a subset of the complete column acq_cc values representing more than 70 unique countries. I want to replace the 2 letter country code by a number

`acq_cc =  {KY, US, CN, SG, US, SG, US, US, CZ, CN}`

The above subset should be converted into the column below so I could use it as an predictor.

`acq_cc = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you can use the pandas built-in:

```
acq_cc = pd.factorize(var, sort=True)[0]
```

where in `var` you can directly pass the pandas column or your `acq_cc`

Comment: One word: Amazing!!! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! So, vote my answer as accepted by clicking the green symbol under the down arrow @pangelbird

Comment: Done, already did that but needed to wait 5 minutes. There you go!